# Nuxt Caching & Keeping Routes Alive

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Hope someone have answers for my nuxtJs questions, Thanks in advance.

> First, I want to know why is nuxt SSR refetching the scripts every time I change the route, If you were to visit: https://coupongb-nuxt.herokuapp.com/ & open the Network in the dev tools, Then click on one of the products you'll notice the components & chunks needed are loaded, But when getting back to the home page Nuxt would redownload the components & chunks... Isn't it supposed to cache then ?
>
> Second, Since the website I'm creating is very simple, I want to know how to tell nuxt to "keep alive" the home page, in other words not keep the state of it as it is even after visiting another route and returning. The reason why I want it this way is because I'm using infinite scrolling, and when the user comes back to the home page he must find all the products that were loaded before.

Please forgive any grammar mistakes, I'm not a native speaker.
Thanks again.

Comment: Is this still relevant? Do you have any code examples?